# Logical error while inserting elements in to Two dimensional array using Scanner

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to sum of rows of Matrix
When I just put elements in 2D array output is right but when I'm trying using Scanner output result is different

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
2
1 2 
3 4
```

**Output:**

```
3
7
```

Below code result correct

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 int a[][] = {       
                        {1, 2,},    
                           
                        { 3, 4}    
                    };    

int rows, cols, sumRow, sumCol;    
            
        //Initialize matrix a  
              
          //Calculates number of rows and columns present in given matrix    
          rows = a.length;    
        cols = a[0].length;    
            
        //Calculates sum of each row of given matrix    
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){    
            sumRow = 0;    
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){    
              sumRow = sumRow + a[i][j];    
            }    
            System.out.println(sumRow);    
        }    
            
        //Calculates sum of each column of given matrix    
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){    
            sumCol = 0;    
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){    
              sumCol = sumCol + a[j][i];    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result incorrect if I'm trying with Scanner**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int row = sc.nextInt();

int column = sc.nextInt();

int [][] a = new int[row][column];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
       
    a[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
    }
}

int rows, cols, sumRow, sumCol;    
            
        //Initialize matrix a  
              
          //Calculates number of rows and columns present in given matrix    
          rows = a.length;    
        cols = a[0].length;    
            
        //Calculates sum of each row of given matrix    
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){    
            sumRow = 0;    
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){    
              sumRow = sumRow + a[i][j];    
            }    
            System.out.println(sumRow);    
        }    
            
        //Calculates sum of each column of given matrix    
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){    
            sumCol = 0;    
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){    
              sumCol = sumCol + a[j][i];    
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem([link](https://onlinegdb.com/HJkEEZCCU))  show some example for which it gives incorrect answer. Your sample input is incorrect, you don't input column size

Answer (score 2):

With the sample input you've provided, you shouldn't be reading the number of rows and columns, but just a single int for the number of both rows and columns:

```java
int size = sc.nextInt();

int [][] a = new int[size][size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {       
        a[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: But how about if we have 2x3 matrix? Thanks by the way your answer works good for same size matrix

Comment: @User75432132 the sample input doesn't seem to allow a 2x3 matrix. Can you provide sample input to show how you' d like to receive such a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any logical problem with your code. However, it is equally important to keep your code clean and user friendly. I recommend you address the following points if you are serious about programming:

1. The following declaration is unnecessary:

   ```
   rows = a.length;
   cols = a[0].length;
   ```

   You can simply use `row` and `column` instead of creating `rows` and `cols` for the same thing.

   You should remove all such unnecessary things which create noise in your code.
2. You have missed printing the sum of each column i.e.

   ```
   System.out.println(sumCol);
   ```
3. You do not need to declare `throws IOException` with `main` for this code.
4. You should always display a message describing the input; otherwise, the user remains clueless about what he/she is supposed to input.

   Given below is the code incorporating these comments:

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
           int row = sc.nextInt();
           System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
           int column = sc.nextInt();

           int[][] a = new int[row][column];
           for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
               System.out.println("Enter " + column + " integers: ");
               for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                   a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
               }
           }

           int sumRow, sumCol;

           // Calculates sum of each row of given matrix
           for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
               sumRow = 0;
               for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                   sumRow = sumRow + a[i][j];
               }
               System.out.println("Sum of row " + i + ": " + sumRow);
           }

           // Calculates sum of each column of given matrix
           for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
               sumCol = 0;
               for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                   sumCol = sumCol + a[j][i];
               }
               System.out.println("Sum of column " + i + ": " + sumCol);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   **A sample run:**

   ```
   Enter the number of rows: 3
   Enter the number of columns: 4
   Enter 4 integers: 
   1 9 2 8
   Enter 4 integers: 
   2 8 3 7
   Enter 4 integers: 
   3 7 4 6
   Sum of row 0: 20
   Sum of row 1: 20
   Sum of row 2: 20
   Sum of column 0: 6
   Sum of column 1: 24
   Sum of column 2: 9
   Sum of column 3: 21
   ```